# Collection locking and synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading

I am working on an application and that needs to load data from Amazon SQS to my database, Sounds easy? Well, it is.

But here is the fun part, So basically I will receive a message from SQS one by one and after doing some massaging on the message I am mapping this to a my entity and then persisting this entity to my database.
In short flow is like.

**SQS->Consumer->Consumers map messages to entity->database**.

But the thing is I don't want to open the db connection every time I recieve a message from queue (as frequency of incoming is high), so what I want to do is receive a message save it in a collection and a flush job will run in every 10 minutes and will flush the collection to DB.

1. I want to ensure that when the flush job is running then the
   collection should not be updatable when the job completes only then
   the collection (list) should be updatable.
2. I also don't want to make my consumer idle when the flush job is running every message I receive while flush is running must be available for the next batch or say when the next time flush job will run.

I am not familiar with the concepts of the thread, collections locking/unlocking synchronization in Java, but I feel there must be solution for my case using these concepts.

Comment: Use a connection pool if you think creating database connections has overhead. Only try to do something like this if you have a real and very big performance problem. The solution you are considering is going to make your code more complex, more prone to bugs, and chances of dataloss gets bigger.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion if you don't want to create connection to database each time instead of running task each 10 minutes you can use connection pooling, when you have a queue of already created connections, and you just retrieve one of these connections from the pool. perform some work, and then instead of closing connection you just put it again to the queue. You can also combine these approach with job batching, and instead of writing objects by 1, you can as you said wait for some number of object to be ready and then retrieve a connection. There is a lot of libraries doing this connection pooling, and I described the simplest connection pool, of course there much other things in there, you can just search it, there are plenty articles regarding this.

Anyway, answering your question about collections:

There are lots of `ThreadSafe` collections in java, and there are different ways of communicating between threads.

If you are sure that you don't want to write to collection while you are reading from it, then you can use just a usual `Queue`(e.g. `ArrayQueue`),
and when reading/writing you just call `synchronized` on it, then you can do anything with collection during this synchronized block, and you don't need to even use `ThreadSafe` collection then, however this approach is usually believed to be not the optimal one.

I think in your case you can use any concurrent queue(for example `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`), it is `ThreadSafe` meaning that you can safely perform `read/write` operations from different threads. So your job will look like:

```
int currentSize = queue.size();
List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<Entity>(currentSize);
for(int i = 0; i < queue.size(); ++i) {
    entities.add(queue.poll());
}

try (connection = connectionPool.getConnection()) {
     //call batch job with entities
} finally {
    connectionPool.returnConnection(connection)
}
```

And your `Consumer` which is creating this entities would just perform an `add` operation on the same Queue, and you don't need to care if they are doing these operations at the same time.

Here you can see that I first get the `size` from queue, and only then iterate through it. That is because in case you have another thread constantly adding new entities to that queue, without this you will be just infinitely reading from queue never proceeding to actual task, so we just want to read all entities which were in a queue at the moment when we started running current task. All other entities would be processed on the next task call.

But in my opinion if you don't have huge amount of data to constantly process, you may be don't even need batching. Without batching your code would look like:

```
Entity e = queue.poll();
if (e != null) {
    try (connection = connectionPool.getConnection()) {
     //call batch job with entities
    } finally {
        connectionPool.returnConnection(connection)
    }
}
```

Comment: Message frequency in queue is around 30msg/second, should I go for the later approach in this case?

Comment: @user2912611 30msg/s is not really high throughput requirement, so probably you don't need batching, and just a usual connection pool should be enough. But in case you are not sure, you should probably ask smb from your team/company, as it always depends from particular database and its setup, but anyway imho 30msg/sec isnt a lot.

Comment: @user2912611 did my answer resolved your issue or you have any further questions? If its resolved please approve the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A BlockingQueue with predefined capacity you can use to receive messages,  consume only as chunk and flush to data base.

Comment: there is no option to receive messages from SQS in chunk.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you make use of a monitor or a semaphore in order to ensure mutual-exclusion between any threads that are taking part in this activity.

I don't have an IDE by my hand now, so the code may have some syntax errors:

```
public class SQSMonitor {

    private ArrayList<ThingsToFlush> list;

    public SQSMonitor(){
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }
       // Note the use of syncrhonized keyword    
    public synchronized void enqueueElement(ThingToFlush element){
        this.list.add(element);
    } 
        // Note the use of syncrhonized keyword
    public synchronized void flushToDB(){
        // flush to db code...
        Iterator<ThingToFlush> it = this.list.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            db.insert(it.next());
        }
    }

}
```

And the Semaphore example:

```
public SQSMutex {
    // Only one process can access the list.
    private Semaphore mutex = new Semaphore(1);
   private ArrayList<ThingToFlush> list = new ArrayList<>();

   public void enqueueElement(ThingToFlush item){
       mutex.acquire();
       this.list.add(item);
       mutex.release();
   }

   public void flushToDB(){
      mutex.acquire();
      Iterator<ThingToFlush> it = this.list.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()){
         db.insert(it.next());
      }
      mutex.release();
   }
}
```

To fully understand the code I'd recommend you to take a look what Semaphores and Monitors are and how to use them properly.

Comment: Also, if you don't want your consumer to go iddle while the other process is dumping the items, you can switch "mutex.acquire" with "mutex.tryAcquire()" and if that instruction returns false, exit the method and keep your consumer thread busy doing other business.